# IN Thread-Safe How to write Map and other thread read

Tags: java, android

How to write in  Thread-Safe  Map and other thread read it thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to write a `ConcurrentHashMap`, use [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: I updated the link, but I'm pretty sure it's the same document

Comment: I think beggars shouldn't be choosers, and Java developers should know how to find APIs online. @uʍopǝpısdn gave him the the tidbit he needed to find it himself.

Comment: @CodeChimp - I'm not the "beggar" in this context.  My point it is that if you point newbies at the old javadocs, they may not realize that more up-to-date stuff is available too.  And while Java developers *should* be able to find the APIs, you would be surprised how many can't.  (I blame their lecturers ...)

Comment: And who's to say the OP was using the latest JVM?  And, fundamentally, what has changed in CurrentHashMap anyway.  If you didn't like the reference he provided then you are free to edit @uʍopǝpısdn's post and fix it.  Don't bash him because he tried to help someone, as it discourages him from trying to help next time.